# CiviCRM Multi-site support under drupal 8

Tags: multisite, drupal-8, integration

Does anyone do CiviCRM Multisite under drupal 8?
We have lots of affiliates and would like to put them all in the same civicrm database with ACLs set up per domain.

Does this work the same way it did with Drupal 7?

It seems like if you were running Drupal 8 multisite as well, and have discrete drupal 8 databases for each subdomain, you'd run into drupal contact id collisions that would play havoc with the drupal -> civi contact mappings.

If there's no difference between drupal 7/8 with civicrm I'll just read the documentation for drupal 7

Anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set up a multisite with drupal 8 alongside a drupal 7 but not multiple drupal 8 sites.

The existing drupal 7 documentation was enough to go off. Definitely would recommend trying it out on a demo site first.

Comment: thx! I'll definitely see if there are issues with user.id collisions... hopefully we're matching drupal users to civi contacts using GUIDs, which should be guaranteed.